# Show Info Windows of the elements which are clicked hide the others

Tags: html, google-maps, knockout.js, frontend

Am trying to display the locations in map which i have in my array i have listed the locations on the left side. if user click any of the locations on the list the map should display that particular location and info Window. The problem here is if i click on any other location the previous clicked info Window still appears on the map how can i hide it in the map?

My [code](https://github.com/kannan007/Neighborhood-Map)

Comment: https://github.com/kannan007/Neighborhood-Map here is my repo

Comment: show code  not link ..

Comment: http://codepen.io/kannant14/pen/KWdWWN here you go

Comment: The window is hidden for me in your example (on Chrome). Or maybe I didn't get your issue?

Comment: Bro click one or more locations then only you will get to know what am saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating a new `infoWindow` instance every time you click one of those locations and not saving them for further use.

i have modified your code inside **two functions**

```
1. populateInfoWindow
   (added condition here to check if there is an infoWindow created already,
    if yes then use that else create new and save it under the same marker)

2. showListings    
   (if marker visibility is false then call close function of its infoWindow)
```

working [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZebyRQ)

Comment: Bro there? there is an another problem

Comment: Cleared myself bro Thanks